# Stuck in a tping loop away from the command block on singleplayer and I do not know where the coordinates are

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am stuck in a command block teleporting loop, and I am far away from the command block. I don't know the coordinates or anything. Please help :c

Comment: Use NBTExplorer to edit your position or the data of commandblock itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the world on a server and in server properties disable command blocks. This would allow you to find the command block that is teleporting you and remove it and then re-enable command blocks after you removed it. You don't have to buy a server or port forward or anything, just simply download the server.jar for the version of minecraft you were using and direct connect too "localhost".

Comment: How? I don't know how... :c I just got MC like a month ago

Answer (score 0):

if you know the Coordinates of the Commandblock you can try:

```
setblock [X] [Y] [Z] air
```

that destroys the Command Block and you're Free

Comment: I don't know the coordinates, I just said that!! :c